# API returns a list of Abilities for each Consumer, what does True/False refer to?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

As per, User Details | Jack Henry Digital Toolkit | Jack Henry Docs, your API returns a list of Abilities for each Consumer, primarily with a true or false value. Such values include things like BillPay, P2PEnable, PaymentCardManagement etc.

My question is what does the True/False value refer to?

- Does it indicate that the Ability is available to the consumer?
- Or does it indicate whether the Consumer has activated/enrolled in the Ability?

We cannot determine.

Thank you

Comment: For clarification, are you asking about the [GET /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/details](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/consumers/details/#/Retrieve%20user%20details/get_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__details) endpoint from the Admin API?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're referring to the [GET /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/details](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/consumers/details/#/Retrieve%20user%20details/get_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__details) endpoint from the Admin API, then the boolean value is `true` if the ability is available for that particular user.

It's not meant to signal enrollment or activation.